# How to make image and video slider with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, slider, carousel

I want to make image and video slider with bootstrap. But the slider which ı made isn't working well. For example; Slider didn't wait videos and videos didn't play automatic. I search this problem on google. But, I didn't find result.

Comment: Can you show us the code of your slider, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you include css and js files properly as described in
[bootstrap documentation of carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/) it should work.

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

To control carousel programmatically you can use javascript events

```
slide.bs.carousel
slid.bs.carousel
```